# java.lang.StackOverflowError en formulario utilizando Spring Boot y Thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Es la primera vez que escribo por acá, tengo un problema al tratar de guardar por formulario un objecto en la BD SQL. Me larga el siguiente error:

```
>Whitelabel Error Page
>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

>Wed Mar 04 10:58:26 ART 2020
>There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>No message available
>java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Utilizo dos Controladores para manejar el llenado de una factura, dividida en Items, pie y Encabezado.

Clase encabezado:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name="facturas_encabezado")
public class Encabezado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3479505724865821556L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private Timestamp fecha;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1,max = 11)
    private String numero;
    @Nullable
    private String letra;
    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    private Cliente cliente;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "encabezado")
    private List<Item> items;
    @NotNull
    private Boolean anulado=false;
```

Clase Item:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="facturas_items")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3560761383569266746L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productos_id")
    private Producto producto;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "facturas_encabezado_id")
    private Encabezado encabezado;
    private BigDecimal cantidad;
    private BigDecimal precioUnitario;  
    private BigDecimal subTotal;
```

Encabezado Controller:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/factura")
public class EncabezadoControl {
    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepositorio clienterepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductoRepositorio productorepository;
    @Autowired
    private EncabezadoRepositorio encabezadorepository;

    @GetMapping("/creacion_factura")
    public String creacionFactura(Encabezado encabezado,Errors errors,Model model ) {
        List<Cliente> clientes;
        clientes=clienterepository.findByVisibilidad();
        model.addAttribute("titulo", "Listado de Clientes");
        model.addAttribute("data", clientes);
        model.addAttribute("encabezado",new Encabezado());

        return "facturas/creacion_factura";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/creacion_factura")
    public String guardarFactura(Encabezado encabezado,Errors errors,Model model) {
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); //Instanciamos fecha actual para el encabezado de factura.
        encabezado.setFecha(timestamp);
        model.addAttribute("facturaInfo",encabezado);
        System.out.println(encabezado);

        if(encabezado.getId()==null){
            encabezadorepository.save(encabezado);
        }
        Long id=encabezado.getId();
        return "redirect:/factura/establecer_productos/"+id;
    }

}
```

Item Controller:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/factura")
public class ItemControl {
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepositorio itemrepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductoRepositorio productorepository;
    @Autowired
    private EncabezadoRepositorio encabezadorepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/establecer_productos/{id}")
    public String indicarProductos(Model model, @PathVariable Long id){

        List<Producto> listaproductos=null;
        listaproductos=productorepository.findByEstado();

        model.addAttribute("titulo", "Selección de Productos");
        model.addAttribute("productos",listaproductos);

        model.addAttribute("item", new Item());


        return "facturas/seleccion_productos";
    }


    @PostMapping(value = "/establecer_productos/{ided}")
    public String procesarProductos(@PathVariable Long ided, Item item,Model model){

        if(item.getId()==null) {
            BigDecimal cantidad = item.getCantidad();
            BigDecimal precio = item.getPrecioUnitario();
            item.setSubTotal(cantidad.multiply(precio));
            item.setEncabezado(encabezadorepository.getOne(ided));
            itemrepository.save(item);
        }
        System.out.println("ITEM\n\n\n"+item+"\n\n\n");
        return "redirect:/factura/establecer_productos/"+ided;
    }

}
```

HTML de el primer paso de la Creacion de Factura: (el de encabezado):

```
div class="container">

        <form method="post" th:action="@{/factura/creacion_factura}" th:object="${encabezado}">
            <br/>
            <h2>Introduzca los datos de la Factura</h2>
            <hr/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3>Cliente</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select name="cliente" class="form-control form-control-lg" th:field="*{cliente}">
                        <option th:each="cliente : ${data}" th:value="${cliente.id}" th:text="${cliente.nombre}"></option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('numero')} ? 'form-group row has-danger' : (*{numero == null} ? 'form-group row' : 'form-group row has-success')">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3>Numero Factura</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input th:field="*{numero}" type="text" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('numero')} ? 'form-control form-control-danger' : (*{numero == null} ? 'form-control' : 'form-control form-control-success')" placeholder="Ingrese el numero de factura" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('numero')}" class="form-control-feedback">El número debe tener entre 1 y 11 caracteres</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('letra')} ? 'form-group row has-danger' : (*{letra == null} ? 'form-group row' : 'form-group row has-success')">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3>Categoria Factura</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control form-control-lg" th:field="*{letra}" >
                        <option th:value="'A'"th:text="A"></option>
                        <option th:value="'B'"th:text="B"></option>
                        <option th:value="'C'"th:text="C"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block">Siguiente Paso</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

HTML del segundo paso de la creación de Factura (Item):

```
<div class="container">

    <form method="post" th:action="@{/factura/establecer_productos/{id}(id=${id})}" th:object="${item}">
        <br/>
        <h2>Seleccione los Productos de la Factura</h2>
        <hr/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3>Productos</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="producto" th:field="*{producto}">
                    <option th:each="producto : ${productos}"  th:value="${producto.id}" th:text="${producto.nombre}"></option>
                z</select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h4>Cantidad</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control text-center" th:field="*{cantidad}" type="text" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('cantidad')} ? 'form-control form-control-danger' : (*{cantidad == null} ? 'form-control' : 'form-control form-control-success')" placeholder="introduzca cantidad a comprar" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cantidad')}" class="form-control-feedback">La cantidad es obligatoria</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h4>Precio Unitario</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control text-center" th:field="*{precioUnitario}" type="text" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('precioUnitario')} ? 'form-control form-control-danger' : (*{precioUnitario == null} ? 'form-control' : 'form-control form-control-success')" placeholder="introduzca precio unitario" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('precioUnitario')}" class="form-control-feedback">El precio es obligatoria</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn block">Siguiente</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Creo que eso seria todo. El problema radica en que al momento de iniciar la creación de la factura. En el primer paso no hay problema, se crea en la BD el registro del encabezado. En el segundo paso a la hora de seleccionar el producto, cantidad y precio, y darle a siguiente. Larga error pero guarda también en la BD el registro correspondiente. La idea principal de todo esto es: una vez en el segundo paso, tener dos botones, uno para añadir otro producto o otro para finalizar digamos. (Esto es por las limitaciones de thymeleaf). ¿ En donde puede estar el problema?

Comment: En tu clase encabezado dependes de la clase item y en la clase item dependes de encabezado, básicamente estas haciendo una dependencia cíclica, al compilar por eso de da el desbordamiento de pila ya que estas saturando el proceso.

Comment: Ah claro, y como puedo solucionar eso?. Por que tambien tengo una clase factura que integra todo digamos. un encabezado, un List<item> items y un pie. Pero no sabría como implementarlo con las limitaciones de thymeleaf y utilizando spring.